# Comparing two sets of variables line by line in unix, code only prints out the very last line

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

this is my first stackoverflow question, regarding bash scripting. I am a beginner in this language, so be kind with me.

I am trying to write a comparison script. I tried to store all the outputs into variables, but only the last one is stored.

Example code:

```
me:1234567

you:2345678

us:3456789
```

My code:

```
#!bin/bash

while read -r forName forNumber

do

  aName="$forName"

   echo "$aName"

  aNumber="$forNumber"

   echo "$aNumber"

done < "exampleCodeFile.txt"

echo "$aNumber"
```

For the first time, everything will be printed out fine. However, the second echo will only print out "3456789", but not all the numbers again. Same with $aName. This is a problem because i have another file, which i stored a bunch of numbers to compare $aNumber with, using the same method listed above, called $aMatcher, consisting:

aMatcher:

```
1234567

2345678

3456789
```

So if i tried to run a comparison:

```
if [ "$aNumber" == "$aMatcher" ]; then

echo "match found!"

fi
```

Expected output (with bash -x "scriptname"):

```
'['1234567 == 1234567']'

echo "match found!"
```

Actual output (with bash -x "scriptname"):

```
 '['3456789 == 3456789']'

echo "match found!"
```

Of course my end product would wish to list out all the matches, but i wish to solve my current issue before attempting anything else. Thanks!

Comment: Good question.  You can make it more readable by formatting code as `code` instead of block quote.

Comment: .... use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your following code

```
aNumber="$forNumber"
```

You are over-writing the variable `$aNumber` for every line of the file `exampleCodeFile.txt` rather than appending.

If you really want the values to be appended, change the above line to

```
aNumber="$aNumber $forNumber"
```

And while matching with `$aMatcher`, you again have to use a for/while loop to iterate through every value in `$aNumber` and `$aMatcher`.

Comment: I tried your method, but it stores everything as one single variable. Is there a way to pass them through one by one? i tried using it as an array but it did not work :/

Comment: Using array should work!! Post your code that you tried using arrays so that you can get help from the members..